# template argument deduction/substitution failed erro, when iterating two maps simultaneously

Tags: c++11, stl, iterator, containers, unordered-map

**I am trying to iterate two unordered maps simultaneously using a pair of two iterators.
This method works fine if we iterate over two vectors;**

```
#include <iostream>
#include<unordered_map>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{ 
    std::unordered_map<std::string,double> mypantry = {{"flour",1.5}};
    std::unordered_map<std::string, int> dubVec = {{"key", 5}};
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> intVec = {"key", "name"};
    double result = 0;

    typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>::iterator intIter;
    typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, bool>::iterator dubIter;

    for (std::pair<intIter, dubIter> i(intVec.begin(), dubVec.begin());
     i.first != intVec.end() && i.second != dubVec.end();
     ++i.first, ++i.second)
    {
        cout << i.first.first << "\n" << i.first.second << "\n" << i.second.second;
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

> prog.cpp: In function 'int main()': prog.cpp:18:70: error: no matching
>   function for call to
>   'std::pair, std::__cxx11::basic_string >,
>   false, true>, std::__detail::_Node_iterator, bool>, false, true>
>
> > ::pair(std::unordered_map, std::__cxx11::basic_string >::iterator,
> >     std::unordered_map, int>::iterator)'
> >          for (std::pair i(intVec.begin(), dubVec.begin());
> >                                                                           ^ In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:0,
> >                      from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/char_traits.h:39,
> >                      from /usr/include/c++/5/ios:40,
> >                      from /usr/include/c++/5/ostream:38,
> >                      from /usr/include/c++/5/iostream:39,
> >                      from prog.cpp:3: /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_pair.h:206:9: note: candidate:
> >     template std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(std::tuple<_Args1 ...>&, std::tuple<_Args2 ...>&, std::_Index_tuple<_Indexes1 ...>, std::_Index_tuple<_Indexes2 ...>)
> >              pair(tuple<_Args1...>&, tuple<_Args2...>&,
> >              ^ /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_pair.h:206:9: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed: prog.cpp:18:70: note:
> >     'std::unordered_map,
> >     std::__cxx11::basic_string >::iterator {aka
> >     std::__detail::_Node_iterator, std::__cxx11::ba

Answer (score 1):

Couple of typos in your code:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> intVec = {"key", "name"};
```

should be:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> intVec = {{"key", "name"}};
//                    notice additional curly brackets ^             ^
```

Previously you tried to initialise your map with a pair of `const char[]`s, but now you initialise it with a single key-value pair.

---

```
typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, bool>::iterator dubIter;
```

should be:

```
typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, int>::iterator dubIter;
```

Previously, `dubIter` was a `typedef` to an iterator of unordered map of string-bool entries, but you have string-int entries in your `dubVec`.

---

```
cout << i.first.first << "\n" << i.first.second << "\n" << i.second.second;
```

should be:

```
cout << i.first->first << "\n" << i.first->second << "\n" << i.second->second;
// notice here ^^                        ^^                          ^^
```

`i` is an `std::pair` of iterators. Its `first` and `second` members are iterators. Iterators to key-value pairs. To access elements of those pairs, you have to either dereference the iterators first, or use `->` syntax, instead of `.`.